# what is the proper way to change a users password in TFS 2013

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I don't see a way through the website administration pages. If I am wrong, please correct me. Most of the searches I found, include ones on this site, said that TFS doesn't have anything built in to change the password.

I have users set up in their own group in Windows and those users have access to certain projects.

A user forgot his password so I was trying to reset it for him. I didn't find anything on the TFS administration webpages and the only place I know to change it is his user in Windows.

When I right click on the user and click change password, I get this message:

[image]

If I do it this way, will it update the TFS info? Is this the proper way to change the user's password in TFS 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TFS doesn't have anything built in to change the password.

Correct. Per [the TFS Authentication and Access page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there are no authentication options 'local' to TFS itself. A standard implementation of Basic authentication uses Windows user accounts, so changing their Windows user credentials will work correctly in TFS.

This does not "update" TFS; TFS simply queries the respective authority in workgroup/domain environments, and authentication will be successful as long as the user's Windows credentials are entered correctly.